# Started using Visual Studio Code v 1.42.1 instead of Anaconda Spyder. Openpyxl 'no module found' in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio

Openpyxl works fine in Anaconda but in Visual Studio Code I am receiving the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'.

When I install it, it shows already installed.

```
C:\Users\XXXXXXX>pip install openpyxl
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)
```

Does anyone have any solutions to get this to work in VS Code?

Comment: You likely need to tell vs code which python interpreter to use.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Python ( 6 weeks now about) and I am unsure exactly what I am doing with that link. Is there any easier explanations?